# How to initialize class non-nullable member with a default non-constant initializer in Dart?

Tags: dart, initialization, initializer-list

I am trying to add default initializer:

```dart
class Foo {
  DateTime? date;
  Foo({this.date}) {
    date ??= DateTime.now();
  }
}

class Foo2 {
  DateTime date;
  Foo2({this.date}) : date ??= DateTime.now(); // <= error
}

void main() {}
```

The only way I fould is to make the member nullable and initialize if within the constructor body.

Is there any better way (to make member non-nullable)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would the following be an acceptable solution? It does require the parameter ,to the constructor, to be nullable and a value of `null` having the implicit meaning of a default value is then used:

```dart
class Foo {
  DateTime date;

  Foo({DateTime? date}) : date = date ?? DateTime.now();
}
```

(And yes, the syntax are correct. Dart are smart enough here to know that we cannot assign a new value to the parameter `date` as part of the initialization phase of constructing the object. So the `date` in `date =` would automatically mean the class variable `date` and not the constructor argument `date`. And since we cannot get any values from the object in this phase either, the second use of `date` is using the class parameter.)

Answer (score 1):

This way, If you don't provide a date when creating the object, it will automatically use the current date and time.

```
class Foo2 {
  DateTime date;
  Foo2({DateTime? date}) : date = date ?? DateTime.now();
}
```

I hope this helps!